# DirectX 11 linking error: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Effects11d.lib'

Tags: hyperlink, directx, linker-errors

I've started to begin my project in directx and already having trouble. First I got a link error with `d3dx11d.lib` that is now resolved however in resolving that error i am now faced with this one

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Effects11d.lib'

and I'm not really sure what to do, directx is still fairly new to me and I just really want to get started.

any help would be much appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is not a standard library that comes with any version of the DirectX SDK.

A quick look on google showed that you probably need to get that lib from the source files of the sample you are looking at.

http://d3dcoder.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=241